# Generating a DECIMAL sequence number in a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, postgresql-9.6

I want to be able to generate a really big sequence number up till 20 bytes in length.

Maximum length which built-in sequence type allows is 8 bytes (bigserial).

So the type which suites my aim is DECIMAL.

```
CREATE TABLE public.ca_params
(
  serial DECIMAL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_serial()
RETURNS NUMERIC AS $$
DECLARE serial_ NUMERIC;
BEGIN
    select serial+1 into serial_ from ca_params
    for update;
    update ca_params set serial=serial_;
    RETURN serial_;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

My question is if I have multiple processes running

```
select generate_serial()
```

will the select clause always return a unique updated value ?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the DML in the function can be simplified to `update ca_params set serial = serial + 1 returning serial;`  No need to first select the old value

Comment: Please tag your postgres version.

Comment: yes, It will. but ALL transactions will wait the working one to release the lock on the table. I don't think such solution is viable

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name
And there would be no lost update ?

Comment: @vao-tsun Are you hinting at `SKIP LOCKED` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps - you both select and update in same `fn()`. check yourself?..

Comment: Why you're storing a single value in a table? Why don't you use a sequence? If the generation of one serial takes 1 micro second, which would be very fast, you will need approx 30000 years to leave the range of `BIGINT`.

Comment: I need to generate serial number for x509 certifiacte. It has up to 20 bytes in length. 
Hm.. May be I should store initial offset as a parameter and add a sequence::next value. Sounds reasonable